# Слетели стили на IE

Tags: css, html5, css3, internet-explorer

В Хроме, Опере, Мазиле со стилями всё ок, в ИЕ ощущение, что даже не включались, что делать в такой ситуации ? Есть вот такая штука в коде, но судя по всему она не очень помогает.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="libs/html5shiv/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/html5shiv/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/html5shiv/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/respond/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Эти условные комментарии сработают на ие ниже 9-й версии, у вас в каком ие всё неправильно отображается? И еще покажите как вы подключаете стили.

Comment: в 8ой, стили вот

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css">

Answer (score 2):

Данные скрипты ссылаются на локальные файлы на вашем компьютере с расширением .js. Вы точно уверены, что эти файлы есть в вашей директории?
Если уверены, то ищите ошибки в путях к файлам.
Если файлов скриптов нет на вашей машине, то ищите эти скрипты на просторах интернета и добавляйте к себе в папки и снова проверяйте/переписывайте маршрут.
Удачи.

Comment: Посмотрел в IE9+ всё окей. Поспрашивал разных людей, получается сейчас кроссбраузерность подразумевает, что IE не ниже 9ой версии, верно ?